# Посчитать площадь под кривой на python

Tags: python, math

Собственно, имеем подобную [ломанную кривую](http://gopractice.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/retention-rate-graph.png) хочется найти апроксимирующую функцию, и посчитать площадь под ней. Хочется не наводящие ответы, вроде, посмотри есть math или scipy, а ссылки на то где есть подобная реализация, или хотя бы. Схожее, я новичок, и реализовать самостоятельно подобное не получается.[image: retention plot]

Comment: А зачем вам искать аппроксимирующую функцию? Возьмите и тупо по значениям посчитайте, в любом случае получится точнее.

Comment: вот [пример, как интеграл посчитать для функции, заданной ломанной кривой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831131/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [numpy.trapz()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)

Пример с использованием Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps
from numpy import trapz

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 21)

y = np.pi / np.exp(x)

# dx - растояние между соседними X координатами
area = trapz(y, dx=5/20)
```

Результат:

```
In [19]: simps(y, dx=5/20)
Out[19]: 3.1204919857832971

In [20]: trapz(y, dx=5/20)
Out[20]: 3.1366600769000623
```

График:

```
In [21]: plt.grid()

In [22]: plt.plot(x, y)
Out[22]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xd5a5c50>]

In [23]: plt.grid()

In [24]: plt.savefig('c:/temp/a.png')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]